# Excluding specific record set from SQL query

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query and wish to retrieve this data set:

```
SELECT 
    Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId, 
    ItemDescription, Status 
FROM 
    PLAYBOOK   
WHERE 
    (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') 
ORDER BY 
    DeliveryDate DESC;
```

However I wish to exclude the dataset retrieved below from the first query:

```
SELECT 
    Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,
    ItemDescription, Status 
FROM 
    PLAYBOOK
WHERE  
    (Supplier = 'PLAY') AND (Status = '0') AND (Tax = 'Yes') 
    AND (Problem = 'damaged');
```

Comment: is `Reference` a unique key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, if you want to take care of Order By also. Else just use `except`

```
select * from 
(
SELECT Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,
ItemDescription, Status  FROM PLAYBOOK
WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0')

EXCEPT

 SELECT Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,
 ItemDescription, Status  FROM PLAYBOOK
 WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') AND (Tax = 'Yes') AND (Problem = 'damaged')
) t1
ORDER BY DeliveryDate DESC
```

Comment: I jumped the gun in voting for the others, they looked elegant but didn't work. This did.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the additional conditions

```
SELECT Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,
ItemDescription, Status,  FROM PLAYBOOK
WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') 
AND (Tax != 'Yes') AND (Problem != 'damaged')
ORDER BY DeliveryDate DESC
```

No need for subquery

Comment: Your query can't retrieve records with Tax = 'Yes' and Problem <> 'damaged'.

Comment: @WangWei that is not an OR it's an AND

Comment: Toby only wants to exclude (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') AND (Tax = 'Yes') AND (Problem = 'damaged'), but your query  also exclude the case when Tax = 'Yes' and Problem is something else, not 'damaged'

Comment: @WangWei please internalize the problem again and tell me what's wrong. Take a minute to analyze it

Comment: @WangWei but the one asking the question is not fair he didnt upvote my answer. This world is unfair :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the one query:

```
SELECT Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,ItemDescription, Status
FROM PLAYBOOK
WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') AND ((Tax <> 'Yes') AND (Problem <> 'damaged'))
ORDER BY DeliveryDate DESC;
```

Comment: Same with my answer though :3 and answered it early

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question (without offering comment on whether what you ask for is a good idea):

```
SELECT Reference, DeliveryDate, SecondaryDate, PurchaseId,
ItemDescription, Status,  FROM PLAYBOOK
WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') AND (Status = '0') 
AND Reference NOT IN (
   SELECT Reference FROM PLAYBOOK
   WHERE (Supplier='PLAY') 
   AND (Status = '0') 
   AND (Tax = 'Yes') 
   AND (Problem = 'damaged')
)
ORDER BY DeliveryDate DESC
```